# How do I make an API call from html5 script to django rest framework?

Tags: html, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a simple login view using html5 and Django rest-framework for a project but when I give the correct data the server responds with an alert saying "undefined" and won't give back the token.

[Alert message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCLWi.jpg)

HTML file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        function sendForm() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8000/auth/signin",
                data: JSON.stringify({'username': $('#username').val(), 'password': $('#password').val()}),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    print(data)
                    if (data.message == "ok") {
                        window.location = "http://localhost:8000/";
                    } else {
                        alert("function");
                    }
                },
                failure: function (errMsg) {
                    alert("Se presentó un error al intentar el login");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" onsubmit="return sendForm();">
    Usuario<input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Usuario"/><br/>
    Contraseña<input id="password" name="password" type="password"/><br/>
    <input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="login"/><br/>
    <a href="http://localhost:8000/">Cancelar</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The HMTL file has a script to make a POST using the information from the form and sends it in a JSON format to the API.

Django rest API

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .logic import signin as do_signup, signout as do_signout
from .serializers import UserSerializer


@api_view(["POST"])
def signin(request):
    username = request.data.get('username', '').lower()
    password = request.data.get('password', None)

    try:
        user, token = do_signup(request, username, password)
        return Response({
            'token': token,
            'data': UserSerializer(user).data,
        }, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'error': str(e)}, status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)


def login_user(request):
    return render(request, 'portal/login.html')


@api_view(["POST"])
def signout(request):
    do_signout(request, user=request.user)
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```